# How to award a second bounty on an existing answer?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounty

I want to place a bounty of 200 on an existing answer to thank someone for helping answer my question, but when I click "Add bounty", my only option is "500". That is too much. A previous bounty went to another user. How can I award a smaller bounty?

Answer (score 6):

[You *can't:*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/159019)

> We now double the minimum "spend" for successive bounties *on the same question by the same user*. So if you started at 50: your next bounty on that question has a minimum of 100, the next 200, the next 400, the next (max).